# unable to generate solr schema with cassandra datastax

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I'm using datastax enterprise 5.0.2 and I want to use solr

I try this :

> dsetool create_core keyspace.table generateResources=true reindex=true

But I get this :

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Type org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ByteType is not supported with automatic Solr schema generation.
Specify 'lenient: true' in your resource generation options to ignore unsupported columns.
```

And when I try with lenient true I can't make it work either because my primary key has a byte field named 'type'

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: Schema Parsing Failed: Schema contains no indexed field for element 'type' of composite key '(lang,type)
```

Any clue how to resolve this ?

My table has over 100 fields it will be hard to generate it manually

Comment: Do you get a response if you use `infer_solr_schema` ? https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsetool.html#dsetool__inferSolrschema

Comment: no, the byte type is not supported even when mapping manually and/or in lenient mode

Comment: If you can generate duplicate dummy table without this byte type then create the schema from that then you could use this to for the original table. You might possibly be able to set `stored=false` and `indexed=false` and still have it in the schema

Comment: Already tried that, but doesn't work either. I ended up using int, not the best solution but a working one

Answer (score -2):

Take out the

> reindix=true.

On first creation just do it like this:

> dsetool create_core keyspace.table generateResources=true

later on you can reindex